# Is there a way to stop elm.init() in gulp-elm from moving elm-stuff and elm-package.json into the parent directory?

Tags: node.js, gulp, elm

I'm trying to use [gulp-elm](https://github.com/philopon/gulp-elm) with a monolithic architecture. I have setup my project dir with client and server directories and I've put my gulp file in the main directory. The directory structure is pretty simple.

```
project/
    gulpfile.js
    package.json
    client/
        elm-package.json
    server/
        ...
```

When i run, for example, 
`gulp elm-init`
with the following task:

```
// File paths
var paths = {
  dest: 'client/dist',
  elm: 'client/src/*.elm',
  static: 'client/src/*.{html,css}'
};

// Init Elm
gulp.task('elm-init', function(){
  return elm.init({ cwd : 'client' });
});

// Compile Elm to HTML
/*gulp.task('elm', ['elm-init'], function(){
    return gulp.src(paths.elm)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(elm({ cwd : 'client' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest));
});*/
```

the `elm-stuff` folder and `elm-package.json` get moved to the main project directory. Is this expected? if not, is there a correct way to use a gulpfile from the parent directory to build an elm package in a nested directory? I think my effort matches the [example](https://github.com/philopon/gulp-elm/blob/master/example/gulpfile.js).

```
gulp.task('init-nested', function(){
  return elm.init({cwd: 'elm/nested-elm/'});
});

gulp.task('nested', ['init-nested'], function(){
  return gulp.src('elm/nested-elm/*.elm')
    .pipe(elm.make({filetype: 'html', cwd: 'elm/nested-elm/'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/'));
});
```

I've tried looking at the source, as well as following dependencies to see if i could figure it out myself, but i'm relatively unfamiliar with node so it's hard for me to figure out exactly what's going on in the [gulp-elm source](https://github.com/philopon/gulp-elm/commit/c6027e15378d783c36f492a558ecfcd4442dc28b) (as well as [one of the deps](https://github.com/IndigoUnited/node-cross-spawn) i checked out.)

Comment: I've tried recreating this, using the files at https://gist.github.com/bdukes/8f23430ba4b4ec57d03ff80e1e6053ac (pretend `client__elm-package.json` is `client/elm-package.json`), and I'm not seeing any files copied.  Is it possible there's something else going on in your Gulp process?

Comment: It's probably very possible haha. I will update my repo so you can poke around and look into it some more later tonight. I am using [this tutorial as a guide from Auth0](https://auth0.com/blog/creating-your-first-elm-app-part-1/) as well as [this gist showcasing gulp with golang](https://gist.github.com/squidfunk/120b6f02927fdc9ef9f1). I'm also not super familiar with gulp, but I'm under the impression that running `gulp elm-init` would only run the task named `elm-init`, as described in the question, and I imagine elm.init() shouldn't really do anything by itself which is what is so puzzling.

Comment: Thinking about it some more (i'm not at home), it's possible (likely?) that there is something in my package.json, node/npm installation, or the elm-package.json that is dictating the cwd when i run the gulp command. Last night, before i posted, I ran `gulp --cwd client elm-init` which worked, but i don't want to change the cwd for the whole gulp command because I want to use it to run my golang server as well.

Comment: @bdukes https://github.com/senterright/timeframer/tree/build_changes

Comment: @bdukes Ok i think it was because i was using the tutorial's version, which was 0.6.1, your gist has 0.7.1. >:) thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using [this tutorial by Auth0](https://auth0.com/blog/creating-your-first-elm-app-part-1/) which had an old version of gulp-elm in package.json. Ugh!